# Login issue with gconnect() in gtrendsR package

Tags: r, google-account, gtrendsr

I am trying to log into my Google account in R using gconnect() in the gtrendsR package, but am running into issues. I have been doing research using Google Trends data for the last month, and have never had a problem with this.

Please let me know if you have any thoughts. I had Google Support take a look at my account to see if there were any holds or something, but nothing showed up. Also tried logging in through another account which didnt work..

This is what I am trying to do:

```
usr <- 'my_username@gmail.com'
psw <- 'my_password'
gconnect(usr, psw)
```

And then I am returned with the following error:

`Google login failed! Check your login information.NULL`

Comment: I get this error while connecting Error in strsplit(val, "[:=;]")[[1]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: If you have two-factor authentication enabled with your Google account you might need to use an application-specific password

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no quick solution for gtrends. However, I discovered a [URL which directly downloads the data](https://www.google.com/trends/trendsReport?hl=tr&q=YOURQUERY&tz=Etc%2FGMT-3&content=1&export=1).

This url is the link of 'download as csv' menu in Google Trends. However, direct fetching from R by download.file function is problematic.

Answer (score 1):

See this page: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps.  Try switching to "on" if the setting is "off".

Comment: So I have a 2-step authentication and the article states if you are using Mac OSX of latest version, it's not an issue to access Google despite having 2 - step auth. Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Log into your Google Account again and check if it works now. I had the same problem but miraculously everything works again today. It seems to me as if Google sometimes moves accounts into some sort of quarantine state and releases them after a  while.