# gtrendsR gconnect authenticatePage2 gives error code 400

Tags: r, curl, google-trends, gtrendsr

I try to connect from a Proxy-server and I could access gtrends data until mid last week in this way. Now I can still sign up through Internet Explorer, but not through gconnect. Google does not ask for any additional verification when connecting through Internet Explorer. I have tried this with 3 different accounts and it is always the same:

`gconnect(username, password)`

> Google login failed! Check your login information.

However when I run gconnect line by line I receive a valid "200" response code for: 
`authenticatePage <- postForm(authenticateURL, .params = formparams, curl = ch)`

However, the following returns a 400 Response code:

`authenticatePage2 <- getURL("https://www.google.com/accounts/CheckCookie?chtml=LoginDoneHtml", curl = ch)`

Why does it authenticate twice in the first place? Isnt it sufficient if the first one works? It seems to me that I have a valid curlHandle, that just does not get passed after authenticatePage2 Fails. Correct?

`sessionInfo()`

> R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
>   Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] dplyr_0.4.3    RCurl_1.95-4.7 bitops_1.0-6   gtrendsR_1.3.3
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>    [1] Rcpp_0.12.1      lattice_0.20-33  zoo_1.7-12       assertthat_0.1   >R6_2.1.1         grid_3.2.3       plyr_1.8.3       jsonlite_0.9.19 
>    [9] gtable_0.1.2     DBI_0.3.1        magrittr_1.5     scales_0.3.0     >ggplot2_2.0.0    googleVis_0.6.0  tools_3.2.3      munsell_0.4.2
>   [17] parallel_3.2.3   colorspace_1.2-6

I am aware that here a similar question is asked, but less detailed:
[Login issue with gconnect() in gtrendsR package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536700/login-issue-with-gconnect-in-gtrendsr-package)

Please, let me know if any more info is required.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @chandler: All of a sudden it works again. Google now asked me to fill in info for 2-step authentification which I skipped. However the previous times I logged in, I was not asked this question. It might be worth to just give it another try now that some time has passed.